# C++ shunting yard algorithm and expression tree implementation

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am new to C++ and using shunting yard algo to build an expression tree. I have been stuck with the problem for a few days. I am trying to get the value of the root node but it fails.

---

Infix input

```
(1+2)*(3/4)-(5+6)
```

The following code is the function based on shungting yard:

```
vector<string> infixToRPN(vector<string> tokens) {
    vector<string> output;
    stack<string> stack;
    string o1;
    string o2;
    //traverse tokens
    for (int i = 0; i < tokens.size(); ++i) {

        // if token is operator
        if (isOperator(tokens[i])) {
            string o1 = tokens[i];
            if (!stack.empty()) {
                string o2 = stack.top();
                while (isOperator(o2) && comparePrecendence(o1, o2) <= 0) {
                    // pop off o2 and on to the output;
                    stack.pop();
                    output.push_back(o2);
                    if (!stack.empty())
                        o2 = stack.top();
                    else
                        break;
                }

            }
            //push o1 on to the stack;
            stack.push(o1);

        }
        //if token is left bracket
        else if (tokens[i] == "(") {
            stack.push(tokens[i]);
        }
        //if token is right bracket
        else if (tokens[i] == ")") {
            string topToken = stack.top();
            while (stack.top() != "(") {
                output.push_back(topToken);
                stack.pop();
                if (stack.empty()) break;
                topToken = stack.top();
            }
            if (!stack.empty()) stack.pop();

        }
        // if token is number and add it to ouput;
        else
        {
            output.push_back(tokens[i]);
        }
    }
    //pop the rest of token
    while (!stack.empty()) {
        string restToken = stack.top();
        output.push_back(restToken);
        stack.pop();
    }
    return output;
}
```

The test result suggests that the parser seems working:

```
12+34/*56+-
```

So I guess the error may take place in my buildTree function. After buiilding, The value returned by getRoot() function is always inconsistent with the correct one. In my case, the root should be "-", while I got a "0".

```
 ExprTree ExprTree::buildTree(vector<string> tokens){
    ExprTree t ;
    TreeNode * n, * n1, * n2;
    TreeNode * r = t.getRoot();
    vector<string> postfix = infixToRPN(tokens);
    stack<TreeNode *> stack;
    for (int i = 0; i < postfix.size(); ++i) {
        //if number


        if (!isOperator(postfix[i])) {
            n = createOperatorNode(postfix[i]);
            stack.push(n);
        }
        else // if operator
        {   
            n= createOperatorNode(postfix[i]);
            if (!stack.empty())
                t = ExprTree(stack.top());
            // pop two tree nodes 
            n1 = stack.top();
            stack.pop();
            n2 = stack.top();
            stack.pop();
            //set children nodes;
            n->setLeftChild(n2);
            n->setRightChild(n1);

            stack.push(n);

        }

    }

    return t;
}
```

Comment: *the error may take place* - What error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your algorithm looks good, but there is an error with the tree you return.

After you have built nodes from your RPN notation, you should have exactly one node left in your stack. Return either that node or a tree whose root is that node.

So, basically:

```
for (int i = 0; i < postfix.size(); ++i) {
   // build tree
}

// enforce that there is only one node on the stack

return ExprTree(stack.top());
```

You could also keep track of the top as you go, but if you do so, you must make the new operator node the top. In your code, you make the right hand operand the top.

Note that in this case, you should also keep track of the top when treating numbers, otherwise you will have a null top node when your expression consists only of a number. Also note that if you do it correctly, yourtop will always be the last item pushed onto the stack – in other words, the stack's top.

Comment: Thanks it is a great help